# Clutch noise after changing gears

Tags: noise, manual-transmission, elantra

I own a Hyndai Elantra Coupe (2013 or 2014, can't remember), and for a time I was changing gears downwards in order to brake (the context is we were taught, in driving school, that you can do this if brakes fail. So I was practicing),

Some time later, it started making a loud "click" noise whenever I changed gears. Specifically, whenever I release the clutch and a gear is selected (meaning the noise doesn't happen on Neutral).

I'm wondering if this noise issue is common enough so that it can be diagnosed by merely describing it, and if so, what's wrong with the transmission?

Comment: Do you have a sense of where the noise is coming from?  For example, is it a pedal sound, something in the shifter, or just an omnidirectional noise?  When exactly does the noise happen?  For example, does the noise happen when the clutch pedal is down and you make the shift?  Or does it happen when the clutch pedal comes back up?  For clarity, I can think of three different click noises that my car will make (none of them bad): one when the clutch pedal hits the stop at the bottom, one on release (the spring pings) and sometimes the shifter taps a piece of trim under the shift boot.

Comment: You could record the noise on video, post it to youtube and share the link.  I'll bet you someone will nail what the sound source is.

Comment: @BobCross I will have a afriend record the noise while I drive and update the question with the Youtube link. It usually happens when I'm letting the clutch go, or when I'm on 1st gear and I let the gas go without pushing the clutch. The sounds seem to come from the transmission.